# Font used in the logo of Safiya Travels

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anybody help me in identifying the font used in the logo of Safiya Travels:

[image]

I have tried using the font-identification websites online, and the closest I could get was Jaunty Gent NF on [MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com):

[image]

Is there a better match?

Comment: I suggest asking here: https://www.reddit.com/r/identifythisfont/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, let me try there